# setting Java_home for in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to write my first map reduce program in hadoop ,when I am starting all the daemons ,I am geting the error that 
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your hadoop-env.sh file and add JAVA_HOME there.

It should be located in the directory where hadoop is installed. (**$HADOOP_HOME/conf**)

Answer (score 0):

check if you have exported java installation path in hadoop-env.sh like this

**export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk**

if you are using hadoop 2.x then you can find hadoop-env.sh at **$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop**